# Develop a valid algorithm that converts a text representation of a binary string to an integer using pseudo code

Tags: binary, pseudocode

Hello guys would like help with the following question:

> You are to design an algorithm to describe the following:
>
> - A function is required that converts a text representation of a binary number to an integer. The binary number may be any length from one (1) to eight (8) digits.
>     Be sure to check that the text string contains only 0s and 1s.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> Input            Output
> 101                5
> 1101001           105
> 10011R           Not a valid binary number
> ```

Here is what I have come up with so far in pseudo code... P.S complete beginner

```
READ inputValue
    SET intValue = inputValue TO INTEGER
    SET n = 0
    WHILE n < 8 DO
       IF intValue = 1
          SET n = n + 1
           PRINT intValue
       ELSE IF intValue = 0
          PRINT intValue
          REPEAT 
          ELSE 
            PRINT Sorry we are not able to validate your input
          ENDIF
        ENDIF
    outValue = n.CALCULATE BINARY OUTPUT
    PRINT outValue
```

Would like if someone can provide some tips on answering this

Comment: sorry btw the example output is beside each binary input in my above examples

Comment: I don't understand your pseudocode. What's with the random indentation?  What does `n.CALCULATE BINARY OUTPUT` mean? Why are you printing things?

Answer (score 0):

The way you compute the value your binary number is incorrect. 101 represents 1*2^2+0*2^1+1*2^0=5.

Here is how you could read and convert one sample.

```
set n=0
set flag=valid
while read char into c and c not= end_of_line
  if c = '1'
    set n = 2*n+1
  else if c='0'
    set n=2*n
  else
    set flag=invalid
  endif
endwhile
if flag=invalid
   print Sorry we are not able to validate your input
else
   print n
endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I hope the code is human enough for answering the question